# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym_anytrading'

Tags: anaconda, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Windows 10 operating system, Anaconda used.

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix}  -c anaconda gymnasium
```

was successfully completed as well as

```
import sys
!pip3 install gym-anytrading
```

When importing

```
import gymnasium as gym
import gym_anytrading
```

I get this error

```
----> 1 import gym_anytrading

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym_anytrading'
```

Any idea?

Comment: For future reference, you'll have a much better experience in Jupyter if you are using the current best practice when installing inside a Jupyter notebook. Essentially, don't use an exclamation point with `pip install` or `conda install` in the future. Use of the exclamation point can cause issues, see the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez). To insure installations occur in the right environment, the simple magic install commands were added. `%pip install` and `%conda install`. See ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic about the modern magic install commands that insure installation occurs in the environment backing the kernel underlying the active notebook. Of course, as you pointed out in your own answer, in the end this particular package wasn't compatible. Still, if you move to using current best practices when trying to install from inside a notebook, you should have an easier time going forward. Watch out for a lot of outdated information out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that somehow installing with pip3 instead anaconda for which I have not found gym-anytrading **from Jupyter Notebook**, the package was installed in a different and wrong directory with respect to the conda environment in use at that moment and by that Notebook. I have then installed it by pip3 from the command line once inside the folder used by the selected conda environment.

Regretfully, I have then discovered that gym-anytrading appears to be not compatible with TF-Agents because it seems missing some properties and methods of the Gym/Gymnasium environment standards. So I have opened another question here [Compatibility of anytrading Gym environment with TF-Agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75912223/compatibility-of-anytrading-gym-environment-with-tf-agents) and directly in the github public repository issues tracking https://github.com/AminHP/gym-anytrading/issues/88 for which I ask a kind help to the community hoping it will be useful for others too.

Give anyway a read to @Wayne remearks above, they are very useful for installing packages from inside a Jupyter environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `python3 -m pip3 install gym_anytrading`. Some packages are weird with installing. Also see if the conda environment used while running, is being used to install `gym_anytrading`.

Comment: thank you, i discovered that somehow installing with pip3 instead anaconda for which I have not found gym-anytrading, it was installed in a different and wrong directory with respect to the conda environment in use. I have then installed it by pip3 by command line once inside the folder used by the selected conda environment.